# Duplicate js event signals triggered

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have the following html code in my template:

```
<div id="my_choices">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="fast">
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="slow">
    </form>
</div>
```

which is handled the following js code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#my_choices form input[type=radio]', function(){
    var my_form = $(this).closest('form').get(0);
    $(my_form).ajaxSubmit({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/my/url/',
    })
});
```

When selecting a radio button, I often notice, in the network tab of chrome debugger, that the request is sent twice. I doesn't always happen this way, it sometimes just send one signal. The second request always raises `500 internal server error` due to database lock error. I use Sqlite3.

My efforts to fix the duplicate js signals:
- I assumed the problem can be from duplicate consecutive clicks, so I disabled the inputs on trigger, then re-enabled them on handling finished. Nothing, changed
- I assumed the problem can be with the ajax request, so I made the request "synchronous". Of course, it blocked the second event, and there was no error when called the second event. However, the second signal is still sent, and the blocking experience is very bad from user perspective.

Comment: When you click a radio button, two buttons change.

Comment: How, would you please demonstrate, @CL.?. And how to avoid this effect?